# How to load the swagger page by default whenever browse the Azure API URL/Endpoint

Tags: .net-core, swagger-ui, azure-api-apps

I have created an .Net Core Web API application and then enabled the swagger definition for this API application.

This is the Startup.cs file

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Register the Swagger generator, defining one or more Swagger documents
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1",
                new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = "Demo Web API", Version = "v1" });
        });
        //services.AddControllers();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();

        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger();

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui(HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
        // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
        {
            options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Demo Web API");
            //options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
            //options.DocumentTitle = "Demo Web API";
            //options.DocExpansion(DocExpansion.List);
        });

    }
}
```

I have published this application into Azure API App. After that I’m trying to browse the Azure API App default URL then it’s not loading the swagger page as default one. If I want to see the Swagger UI then I need manually append “**/swagger**” at the end of Azure API App URL.

I need to add the API App as a target into the backend pool of Azure Application Gateway. Whenever I use public IP or DNS name of the Azure Application Gateway then it should display the Swagger UI of the Azure API App.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the `Configure()` method in `Startup.cs` file to load the swagger page by default based on the environment.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui(HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
            // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Demo Web API");
                options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
                //options.DocumentTitle = "Demo Web API";
                //options.DocExpansion(DocExpansion.List);
            });
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Comment: The use of options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty; was the secret sauce. Not very discoverable.

Comment: In asp.net core, you can add a call after the else statement:

`app.Map(() => Result.Redirect("/swagger"));`

instead of `options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;`

app.Map keeps the swagger ui at /swagger, using `options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;` causes swagger to respond to /index.html thru the default document.